# Google Developper Console—Changing authorized URI from command line

Tags: r, google-api, shiny, shinyproxy

So, here's the context:

I'm launching apps from Shiny Proxy, which is a server service for R applications (but that's not the core question).

What this service does is launching a new webpage each time a user connects, with the url (for example) `http://<url>:<port>/app/01_hello/endpoint/xyzabcdef/`, for example — the id of the endpoint being randomly assigned, the stable url being `http://<url>:<port>/app/01_hello`.

I have on this app (01_hello), a button that sends a request for Oauth. If I am on an already launched app, I can go to the google dev console, and manually enter `http://<url>:<port>/app/01_hello/endpoint/xyzabcdefghijklm/` as an authorized URI. And that works.

The thing is that each time I relaunch this app, a new endpoint id is randomly generated. So I can't anticipate what the endpoint will be for future user.

I can catch this id with JavaScript, and send it back to my server.

So my question is: once I get this id back on my server, is there a way to programmatically (in command line) send this url/endpoint/id to the developper console so that this url is authorized?

Maybe there is another (more elegant) way to do this?

Any idea is welcome.